# How to flatten an Observable<Observable<any>> to Observable<any>?

Tags: rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I am trying to get an `Observable<MyType>` by doing the following:

```
return this.cache.get<MyType, number>(storageName, version)
    .map(cached => {
        if (cached !== undefined) {
            return cached;
        }
        return this.http.get<MyType>(`MyTypeGetUrl/${version}`)
            .map(m => m)
            .do(result => {
                this.cache.put<MyType>(storageName, result).first().subscribe();
            });
        }).publishReplay(1).refCount();
```

`cache.get` returns an `Observable<MyType>` and `http.get<T>` returns `Observable<T>`.

I want check the cache for an object, and if it doesn't exist, get it from the server, cache it and return it.

However, if the object exists in the cache, it returns `Observable<MyType>`, but if it needs to go to the server, it returns `Observable<Observable<MyType>>`.

How can I flatten the result from the server, so that I can return an Observable, only calling to the server when I must?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of `map` use `mergeMap` and wrap the cached result into an Observable. In both cases it'll go through `mergeMap` so it'll unwrap `Observable<MyType>` into `MyType` (you could use `concatMap` or `switchMap` as well in this example).

```
return this.cache.get<MyType, number>(storageName, version)
  .mergeMap(cached => {
    if (cached !== undefined) {
      return Observable.of(cached);
    }
    return this.http.get(...);
  })
  ...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use mergeMap and Observable.of like this:

```
return this.cache.get<MyType, number>(storageName, version)
    .mergeMap(cached => {
        if (cached !== undefined) {
            return Observable.of(cached);
        }
        return this.http.get<MyType>(`MyTypeGetUrl/${version}`)
            .map(m => m)
            .do(result => {
                this.cache.put<MyType>(storageName, result).first().subscribe();
            });
        }).publishReplay(1).refCount();
```